# Making an API call when app is not actively running

Tags: ios, swift

I am looking to build an app that will allow a user to send an SMS (through a 3rd party service) at a previously specified time. For this to occur, I will first make a request to my API which in turn will call the 3rd party service.

If a user using my app has removed it from memory (multitask screen) or restarted their phone, how can I ensure that the app still makes the relevant API call at the previously specified time?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can't.  Even if your app is running in the background you can't execute code at a specific time. I suggest you use a server to send the message with your app simply scheduling the request (and perhaps allowing the request to be cancelled) via a web API

Comment: Normally, You can't. But You could send a push notification from your server and make the API call in App Delegate's `didReceiveRemoteNotification:` method

Comment: @NSNoob If the app has been terminated or the device restarted then a silent push will not be sent to the app delegate.

Comment: You are right. This is only valid if the app is neither terminated nor in active state.

Comment: @Paulw11 Would a service like atrigger help with this? https://atrigger.com

Comment: Yes, that looks like it would do the trick.